# How to send http GET request from my Android app and check the response

Tags: android, http, get, httpurlconnection

I am new in Android development and I need some help with **HttpURLConnection**.

What I want to do is to send http get request (by clicking button)  and then check the response (to check response I added TextView to my main Activity).

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendGetRequest(View View) {
    new GetClass(this).execute();
}

private class GetClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final Context context;

    public GetClass(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progress= new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        progress.setMessage("Loading");
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String dataUrl = "http://myurl.com";
        String dataUrlParameters = "email="+"pp@gmail.com"+"&name="+"priyabrat";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
            url = new URL(dataUrl);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String urlParameters = "fizz=buzz";
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode);
            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("output===============" + br);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    outputView.setText(output);
                    progress.dismiss();

                }
            });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is, when I run my app and click the button "Send GET Request", application is stopping with message "Application Was stopped"

Comment: first of all add '?' to the url at the end of the variable dataUrl

Comment: and remove findviewbyid because you can only access the views from the main thread

Comment: and override the method onPostExecute which runs on the main thread where you can modify your views

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some Networking Librarys for Android, they will handle the async stuff for you:

- Volley (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
- Retrofit makes(HTTP API into a Java interface.)(http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- OkHTTP(Retrofit works with it)https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

If you would do it for your own, have a look at the doku from Async Task (
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use the Function:

```
onPostExecute(String output)
```

> invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

And instead of:

```
 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         outputView.setText(output);
         progress.dismiss();
     }
 });
```

make this:

```
return output;
```